# Is component's thread torque a factor in how 'stiff' a bike rides? Would a racer want higher torque?

Tags: maintenance

Is higher pressure into the frame going to reduce vibration and hence improve stiffness?

Comment: You need more specifics, are you talking about the recommended torque amounts for individual components such as derailleurs, cranks, etc? The recommended torque specification for individual parts has nothing to do with the rigidity of a frame, and all to do with A) not cracking or breaking what your tightening into and B) said part not coming loose and falling out bouncing down the road. C) Lawyers

Comment: Nope.  Overtightening things is not going to give you a stiffer frame - because stiffness comes from the frame's material refusing to bend.   Adding stiffness is the same as adding weight, so its always a compromise on the design of the frame.... light enough AND stiff enough.

Comment: If further tightening of a fastener makes the frame stiffer it's because the fastener was not tight enough in the first place.  And, on a conventional frame, the only fasteners that have any effect on frame stiffness are the axle nuts.

Comment: On the other hand, doing up the suspension pivot bolts really tight would probably make the frame more stiff.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extremely small stiffening effect because the interface contact area increases slightly. But in aerospace we usually consider this a negligible effect. To make a system stiffer all the parts have to become stiffer, which of course does not happen because you tighten a bolt in the system